# Authentication Test Servers

Tags: testing, authentication, ssl, https, ntlm

I'm searching for examples of public **HTTPS** sites that use one of the following authentication types - these sites will be used as test servers for an application currently under development.

**BASIC** authentication
**DIGEST** authentication
**NTLM** authentication

The test servers need to be using SSL as well as one of the above auth types.  Any site suggestions?  Preferably the sites should provide free accounts.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a reliable test system, you should setup your own Apache web server. It can easily provide SSL encryption and basic/digest auth:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

An NTLM module is available as well:

http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/

http://blog.doylenet.net/?p=6

Otherwise you could run into legal troubles for violating the terms of use for public web sites.

Comment: Thanks Wintermute, that's what I went ahead and did.  Like you said, it's the most reliable way to go.

Answer (score 90):

[httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) has public endpoints for HTTP Basic and Digest Authentication (in each example, replace `:user` and `:passwd` with the test values you'd like to check against - `:qop`, too, for Digest):

- [/basic-auth/:user/:passwd](http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd) Challenges HTTPBasic Auth.
- [/hidden-basic-auth/:user/:passwd](http://httpbin.org/hidden-basic-auth/user/passwd) 404'd BasicAuth.
- [/digest-auth/:qop/:user/:passwd](http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd) Challenges HTTP Digest Auth.

Each endpoint is available in both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: <same comment as above>

Comment: By today @heaphach comment still applies  It'd be useful to be able to test all the HTTP verbs with the different auth options, not just `GET`

Comment: The httpbin.org "developer's website" ([kennethreitz.org](https://www.kennethreitz.org/)) links to some interesting pictures under the "humans - F" page (NSFW though)

Answer (score 7):

As an example for testing HTTP authentication:

```
http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/authenticatedimage/default.aspx?0.7349707232788205
```

In order to check a successful authorization you can enter `httpwatch` as the username. It doesn't matter what you enter for the password field, it just needs to be different every time.

---

I also put this link if the above one will not work in the future:

```
http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/#showExample10
```