# example publicly accessible api with basic authentication

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, endpoint

as in title - I know there are api aggregators (e.g. [here](https://any-api.com/)) and fakes/mocks, but I couldn't find any example/mock api that would require basic authentication (and provide credentials for this). Are you aware of any such service in the wild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something which's already been here. Is it what you looking for?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756383/984299

Comment: should I close the question then? It's obviously a duplicate, but I couldn't  find the answer otherwise...

Comment: I'm not sure :) Usually, the moderators do this